# Can Bruce Banner Have Sex Without Becoming the Hulk?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, sexuality

In the marvel movies, they reference how Bruce Banner measures his heart rate and that if it gets too high, that he becomes the Hulk. In the avenger movie, he states how his trick is he is "always angry".

My original understanding was that Bruce becomes the Hulk when he gets angry. But if he is always angry, then this isn't the case, and if its related to just his heart rate, then I'm curious if the Hulk can have sex, as heart rate increases when you approach climax.

**Can Bruce have sex without becoming the Hulk?**

**Clarification:** This is not a question if they can procreate. That is answered in other links, where he has a kid with Shehulk, and an alien chick. They also have a 3rd kid that was created from his DNA and a 4th which is just a rumor. Based on these facts, the only two that are confirmed through traditional methods (sex), where not with ordinary people, which means he may turn into the hulk upon orgasm. The question is can he have sex without becoming the hulk. Him having sex as the hulk is one thing, but him having sex to completion as Bruce is another.

Comment: Yes, he can; http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/949020

Comment: @Richard, that article shows no difference between the positions. Doesn't talk about the increase in blood pressure or HB, even though it states the rates.

Comment: @VenomFangs - The average rates mentioned are well below the rates we see in the film

Comment: @Richard, so is it based on heart rate? I'm curious what really triggers him to become the Hulk. I'm also sad that this question was closed, as procreating is different from having sex without becoming the hulk. The fact that he can breed with another entitiy as the hulk is one thing, but whatever

Comment: @VenomFangs - In the film it seems to be a mix of heart-rate and anger.

Comment: @VenomFangs It's not closed yet. But the other question spells out that Hulk has children and Banner has separate children. If both entities have children, it's fair to assume that Banner can have sex without becoming the Hulk. If you feel this doesn't address your question well enough, explain why and it may avoid closure or be re-opened if it does get closed.

Comment: @phantom42, I'll have to reread through the other article. Did Banner have the kids before or after he became the Hulk? If its after, then yes, it answers my question. If no, then it doesn't.

Comment: @phantom42, I reread the other post and did additional reading beyond it. The Hulk has had 2 kids from breeding. There are references about Banner having kids, but one from his DNA and the other (Carmilla Black), which doesn't have hulk attributes is just rumored to be his kid. So based on this, I don't think there is enough info here to answer my question.

Comment: You are taking the quote too literally. Banner was married to Betty before she was Red She Hulk so they had sex. Carmilla Black aka Scorpion is said to be Banner's (not Hulk's) biological daughter. http://www.comicvine.com/carmilla-black/4005-40706/

Comment: Carmilla Black would have been born before Banner became the Hulk (his other offspring are full-grown due to alien DNA interactions, or being born in a different timeline, as I recall). If she's Banner's love-child w/ Monica Rappaccini (sp?), it dates back to their college days, as I recall. At the point when she was introduced, the Hulk would've been created about 10-11 years ago; she was older than that.

Answer (score 8):

The answers here are exceptional but they ignore the fundamental definitions of the Hulk.

It is not STRESS that causes the change, but DISTRESS. In essence, Bruce Banner cannot become angry. All his intensely negative feelings have become embodied in the Hulk. He doesn't get angry, or hurt, he doesn't swear when he smashes his thumb, he Hulks.

By the same vein, taking a jog wouldn't change him. A rollercoaster wouldn't change him... and sex wouldn't change him. He has to feel pain, a threat, or some intense distress in which case the Hulk will defend him.

Note that the time between distress and response is almost instantaneous. In theory, sniping Banner from a mile away would kill the Hulk, but the instant it takes for his body to die is enough to manifest the Hulk.

Comment: I guess that depends on what you snipe him with....

Comment: The last part of this is definitely not true in light of Hawkeye killing Bruce and then the recent Immortal Hulk series, which makes it quite clear that Bruce/hulk is immortal, and 'killing' Bruce its just a trigger that invariably brings the hulk out. The series also suggests the hulk is more likely to manifest at night.

Answer (score 3):

I own a comic book in which a carny tries to make the Hulk a circus freak by locking Bruce Banner in an electrified cage and dousing him with a mixture of (IIRC) DMSO and adrenaline. It works, but of course the Hulk escapes.
Another story in the same book also showed stress, not anger being the cause of a transformation.

Now this book is a Dutch translation, so I can't vouch for its canonicity, but continuing in this vein, I'd say Bruce Banner *can* have sex, but it has to be really slow and relaxed.